# LibGit2Sharp SshUserKeyCredentials Failed to authenticate SSH session. Callback returned error when git has passphrase

Tags: libgit2sharp-ssh

I am using LibGit2Sharp-ssh (LibGit2Sharp-SSH.1.0.22) nuget package in my C# application to clone some of the git repos. My git private key has the passPharse and when I use SshUserKeyCredentials api with proper Username,Passphrase,PublicKey,PrivateKey values I am getting the below exception when clone the repo.
"Failed to authenticate SSH session. Callback returned error". Do i missing some references. When i have Empty passPhrase the same code base is working fine. If I set passPhrase then it is throwing the above exception. Please help.